# How can I refer my features to my labels? Naive Bayes classifier

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to fit a Machine Learning NB model, and I have everything pretty clean, but can refer my features to my labels, to fit the model:

```py
labels = [[0,0,0,1,1,0],[0,0,1,0,1,1],...]]

features = [[[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5],[0.11,0.21,0.31,0.41,0.51],[0.12,0.22,0.32,0.42,0.52],[0.12,0.22,0.32,0.42,0.52],[0.12,0.22,0.32,0.43,0.53]],[0.13,0.23,0.33,0.43,0.53]...]]]
```

In my problem, [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5] must refer to the first 0 in labels, so the classifier gives a no, [0.11,0.21,0.31,0.41,0.51] refers to the second 0, also a no, [0.12,0.22,0.32,0.42,0.52] refers to the first 1, so that is a yes for the classifier.

How can I fit the NB classifier or rearrange the lists as to be able to fit the model?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hmm... I might be wrong but shouldn’t this be the edit to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56941315/225020)?

Comment: @Jab it could be, yes, i rearrange some things and kind of gotten some same dimension lists, but I lost 95% of my data by doing so. I am currently trying many things at once to see which one gets me to fit the model.

Answer (score 2):

You probably can make use of a wonderful `numpy` library with which you can reorganize the shape of your input data in multiple different ways. One of possible decisions can be as follows:

```
import numpy as np

from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

labels = [[0,0,0,1,1,0],
          [0,0,1,0,1,1]]

features = [[[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5],
             [0.11,0.21,0.31,0.41,0.51],
             [0.12,0.22,0.32,0.42,0.52],
             [0.12,0.22,0.32,0.42,0.52],
             [0.12,0.22,0.32,0.43,0.53],
             [0.13,0.23,0.33,0.43,0.53]],
           [[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5],
             [0.11,0.21,0.31,0.41,0.51],
             [0.12,0.22,0.32,0.42,0.52],
             [0.12,0.22,0.32,0.42,0.52],
             [0.12,0.22,0.32,0.43,0.53],
             [0.13,0.23,0.33,0.43,0.53]]]

labels = np.ravel(labels)
features = np.reshape(features, (-1, 5))

gnb = GaussianNB()
gnb.fit(features, labels)
```